# How can I get a velocity of how much this link is trending?

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, trend

[image]

The above image represents an article's page views over time. X axis is days with 9 being the most recent day. The y-axis is number of pageviews. I'm looking for a decent, not to complex either physics or statistical calculation that would be able to give me (based on the history of the page views) what the current trending of the page views is for the past n days.
So basically, in the past 5 days is this link trending unusually higher than it usually does and if so by what degree/magnitude?

Ideally the answer would provide an algorithm class that applies to this problem as well as some example of that using the data provided from this chart above.

Comment: you should probably include a link to your previous question on [ways to determine if pageviews are trending upward or downward](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11548/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-pageviews-are-trending-upward-or-downward) and clarify how this question is different.